# browser.click not working in safari

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have the following test in nightwatch:

```
browser.click('test')
```

The browser.click function works in chrome but not safari. Does anyone know why it doesn't work in safari?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience this as well, but in your case my best guess is that you're not passing in a correct element, like a class. Example:

```
browser.click('.test')
```

What is the 'test' that you're trying to click?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and apparently the element that I was trying to click on was not in the viewport yet.

I added browser.maximizeWindow() before triggering the click event.

```js
browser.maximizeWindow();
```

I also included waitForElementVisible('.test',1000) before calling click().

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues, a solution for me was to click using Xpath. You can uses Xpath text():

```
 browser.useXpath()
        .click('XpathToElement')
```

also i would inject JS to the browser and try to force a click.

```
browser.execute(function(){
  document.getElementById("nodeId").click();
},[])
```

However be aware that this does not always solve the issue.